# Moving a lightsail instance from subdomain to subfolder

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, amazon-lightsail

We have `www.something.com` domain registered and DNS is managed by AWS. The main domain is a Django App hosted on EC2.

`coolthing.something.com` is a WordPress application (Lightsail instance) 
What we want to do is to move our Wordpress from the subdomain to a subfolder.

Meaning `coolthing.something.com -> www.something.com/coolthing`

Do you guys know any shortcuts other than implementing [reverse proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html) using httpd config to assign Lightsail instance's IP address to www.something.com/coolthing ?

We do not want to touch our main instance also prefer not to use Cloudflare(unless there is no other way)

Thanks in advance for your tips.

Will appreciate having your comments, if you have done such a thing previously.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem moving WordPress install to subfolder you will just need to update "site url" and "home url" in wp_options table, please screenshots below:

[image: Site URL]

[[image: Home Url[2]]

Comment: Oh my problem is not this side of the story, it's about the DNS and hosting side. we have an EC2 instance, one S2 and one Lightsail, the problem is how to assign something.com/coolthing to IP address of lightsail instance in AWS